# Force SQL Server to run query conditions as written?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have this pseudo query (SP) :

```
select ...
from ...
WHERE    @LinkMode IS NULL
     AND (myColumn IN (...very long-running query...))
     ...
     ...
```

The problem is that the query takes a very long time to execute -- even if I execute the SP with `@LinkMode=2`.

*As you noticed, the long-running query should be executed only if @LinkMode  is null, which is not the case here. In my case @LinkMode = 2 !*

However, if I change it to  :

```
 select ...
    from ...
    WHERE    1=2
         AND (myColumn IN (...very long time exeted query...))
     ...
     ...
```

the SP **does** run fast.

I've heard before that sometimes the optimizer *can* optimize the order of criteria.

So I ask :

- Even if the optimizer chooses a different route, what can be faster than checking if `=null`? I mean, *I think that checking `if a==null` is **much** faster than running the other long query...*
- How can I *force* SQL Server to run the query as I've written it (the same order)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are falling into the "*Catch-All Query*" trap, which is explained very well by [Gail Shaw here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries).

To summarize the problem:  SQL Server optimizes away the significant overhead of query compilation by caching a query plan after compilation, and then later checking the cache for a matching query plan before a later compilation.  The "matching" that occurs here is purely textual, so the actual value of a variable will not affect this.

That's *good* 99% of the time, but in some cases it's *bad*.  One case where it's bad is when someone tries to construct a WHERE clause as though its like a short-circuiting IF statement in C, etc.  This doesn't work well, because the SQL compiler has to make ***one*** query plan that will work regardless of what the parameter values actually are, and the only way that it can handle these "clever" logical switching-conditions in the WHERE clause is to make a simple brute-force plan that just scans the whole table, filtering the rows as it goes, without leveraging any indexes.

Not suprisingly, this makes them uniformly slow, no matter what the parameter/variable values are.

Answer (score 8):

There is no guaranteed way to force SQL server to execute your clause conditions in a specific sequence. The optimizer will always evaluate them in the order it sees fit.

What you can do is something like this:

```
IF @LinkMode IS NULL
BEGIN
    select ...
    from ...
    WHERE (myColumn IN (...very long time exeted query...))
         ...
         ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select ...
    from ...
    WHERE ...
         ...
END
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is an option, use an IF statement to execute the appropriate form of the query.  Also, in SQL, you tell the db engine what to do, not how to do it - things are not executed from beginning to end.  It can be hard to predict what exactly it will do.  You probably know this though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL would probably work too, since in that case the query optimizer should get the actual values at run-time *(do correct me if I'm wrong, I'm actually not sure but seem to remember using it for similar situations)*. But I'm with the others in this one, in that an IF / ELSE clause would serve you best, as it's the simplest and easiest solution that will do exactly what's needed.

For future reference in case you haven't used it yet, a horribly ugly site with a working example for dynamic SQL can be found here for instance: http://sqlusa.com/bestpractices/dynamicsql/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the IF/ELSE construct.. If for whatever reason that does not work for you, you can always consider using the WITH RECOMPILE option..

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what the "if/else construct" might look like? :D

Comment: I was going to suggest using OPTION (WITH RECOMPILE), as that would generate an ideal plan each time - the compile delay would add overhead, but I suspect it's better overall in this case.